# fabric.js trigger save state

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm looking for a solution for fabric.js with the stateful-flag set to true.

It's working fine when I'm moving an object around by click drag&drop. The last state is saved in the object. But I also want to move objects with arrow-keys. I can move them but the last state is not saved. I tried to fire some events (after:render, mouse:up, object:modified) but it's not solving the problem.

I hope there is an event I can fire or an workaround to trigger to save the current state. Would be better than implementing a own (duplicated) stateful function.